# Problem while solving a logic expression

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How can I simplify this expression:

$\lnot[(p \rightarrow r) \land (q \rightarrow r)] \land (\lnot p\lor r)$

I tried to solve it and I got the result 0 or F, but the correct answer is:

$\lnot p\land q \land \lnot r$

I would appreciate if someone could help me. I'm on the 10th grade and can't solve this.

Comment: The "correct" answer is ill-formed, it needs parentheses.

Comment: Can you tell me where should I put the parentheses?

Comment: I'd need to check, but if I was forced to guessed I'd say it's supposed to be $(p\land \neg r)\lor r$.

Comment: Can you check your 'correct answer'? Since as stated, that can be further simplified to $p \vee r$  so I doubt it's the correct answer. There is probably a $q$ somewhere in the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong solution. I've edited the question with the correct one.

Comment: Are you using a truth-table?

Comment: I always first replace any $p \rightarrow q$ with its equivalent $\neg p \vee q$, so you're left with just $\neg$'s, $\wedge$'s, and $\vee$'s, for which there are all kinds of simplification rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lnot[(p \rightarrow r) \land (q \rightarrow r)] \land (\lnot p\lor r)$$

$$\begin{align} &= [\lnot (p\rightarrow r) \lor \lnot (q\rightarrow r)]    \land (\lnot p \lor r)\tag{DeMorgan's}\\ \\ 
& = [ \lnot (\lnot p \lor r) \lor \lnot(\lnot q \lor r] \land (\lnot p \lor r)\tag{$a\rightarrow b \equiv \lnot a \lor b$}\\ \\
&\equiv [(p\land \lnot r) \lor (q \land \lnot r)] \land (\lnot p \lor r)\tag{DeMorgan's applied twice}\\ \\
&\equiv [(p \lor q)\land \lnot r]  \land (\lnot p \lor r)\tag{distributive property}\\ \\
&\equiv (*)\quad(p\lor q) \land (\lnot r) \land (\lnot p \lor r)\tag{associative property}\\ \\
&\equiv (p \vee q) \wedge \neg r \wedge \neg p\tag{Reduction principle}\\ \\
&\equiv q\land \lnot r \land \lnot p\tag{Reduction principle}\\ \\
&\equiv \lnot p \land q \land \lnot r\tag{commutativity of $\land$}
\end{align}$$

Now, refer back to $(*)$ in case you're unfamiliar with the Reduction principle.  We can instead, reason our way to the conclusion. Now, notice that because we have three propositions with $\land$'s connecting them, in order for the statement to be true, all three propositions must be must evaluate to true.

That determines $\lnot r$.  And if $\lnot r$, we determine $\lnot p$ from $\lnot p \lor r$.  And since we have $\lnot p$, we must have $q$.

That gives us the conclusion: $\lnot p \land q \land \lnot r$.

Comment: The 'Reduction' principle states that $p \wedge (\neg p \vee q) \equiv p \wedge q$, so from the last statement you can get $(p \vee q) \wedge \neg r \wedge \neg p$, and from that (using Reduction again) you get $q \wedge \neg r \wedge \neg p$

Comment: Thanks @Bram28. I knew I could do that, but I blanked out on justification's name.

Comment: Sure.  And if 'Reduction' is not a rule given to you, you can always derive it as follows: $p \wedge (\neg p \vee q) \equiv (Distribution) (p \wedge \neg p) \vee (p \wedge q) \equiv \bot \vee (p \wedge q) \equiv p \wedge q$

Comment: Thanks @amWhy . I got it now! I appreciate you for spending time to help me :)

Comment: Francisca: you're very welcome! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

$$\lnot[(p \rightarrow r) \land (q \rightarrow r)] \land (\lnot p\lor r) \equiv [\lnot(p \rightarrow r) \lor \neg(q \rightarrow r)] \land (\lnot p\lor r) \equiv [(p \land \neg r) \lor (q \land \neg r)] \land (\lnot p\lor r)$$

One of the disjuncts of the first conjunct must be true, so it must be $\neg r$, and because of that the first disjunct of the second conjunct must be true, so you have $\neg r\land \neg p$, and because of that you deduce the first disjuct of of the first conjunt of your conjunction is false and hence the second one is true, so $q\land \neg p\land \neg r$

Comment: Using 'Distribution', the last statement is equivalent to $[(p \vee q) \wedge \neg r] \wedge (\neg p \vee r)$, so that is just $(p \vee q) \wedge \neg r \wedge (\neg p \vee r)$, which by Reduction is $(p \vee q) \wedge \neg r \wedge \neg p$ which by another Reduction is $q \wedge \neg r \wedge \neg p$

Comment: Sure, my answer is not really a formal derivation, that has been well done in @amWhy's answer. I avoided the last part giving some intuitive argument.

Answer (score 0):

So using that handy Reduction rule, here is another derivation:

$\neg [(p \rightarrow r) \wedge (q \rightarrow r)] \wedge (\neg p \vee r) \equiv$  Implication ($p \rightarrow q \equiv \neg p \vee q$)

$\neg [(\neg p \vee r) \wedge (\neg q \vee r)] \wedge (\neg p \vee r) \equiv$  Reduction

$\neg (\neg q \vee r) \wedge (\neg p \vee r) \equiv$  DeMorgan

$q \wedge \neg r \wedge (\neg p \vee r) \equiv$ Reduction

$q \wedge \neg r \wedge \neg p \equiv$ Association

$\neg p \wedge q \wedge \neg r$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a truth table that may be of help.
$\begin{array}{lcl}
a&\equiv&p\to r\\
b&\equiv&q\to r\\
c&\equiv&a\land b\\
d&\equiv&\lnot c\\
e&\equiv&\lnot p\\
f&\equiv&e\lor r\\
x&\equiv&d\land f
\end{array}$

$\mathtt{pqr·abcdef·x}$
$\mathtt{000·111011·0}$
$\mathtt{001·111011·0}$
$\mathtt{010·100111·1}$
$\mathtt{011·111011·0}$
$\mathtt{100·010100·0}$
$\mathtt{101·111001·0}$
$\mathtt{110·000100·0}$
$\mathtt{111·111001·0}$